# Does the stripe retrieve customer method return the customer or just pass it to the callback?

Tags: async-await, stripe-payments

My code below retrieves the customer inside the callback but not the from the await call.  Other methods seem to pass back an object from the await call so shouldn't retrieve?

```
customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(
          stripeCustomer,
          function (err, customer) {
            // asynchronously called
            sails.log('checkout retreive err ', err);
            if (customer) sails.log('checkout retreived customer.id ', customer.id);
          }
        );
sails.log("checkout customer id after retreive ", customer ? customer.id : 0);
```

log messages:

```
debug: checkout customer id after retreive  0
debug: checkout retreive err  null
debug: checkout retreived customer.id  cus_abc...xyz
```

The stripe docs say the method returns the object.
Thanks

PS: The purpose of the code was to check to see if there was already an active account for a given customer.

Comment: it should return, when i do something like
`let customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(cusId).catch((err) => {return false; }); console.log(customer ? customer.id : false);` works about as expected

Comment: Could the fact that I user the "customer" identifier as the function parameter be my problem then?  I'll need to make some time to test that idea.